# Unable to write to EC2 EFS file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an Ec2 instance in the console, and selected the option to add an EFS file system. Once the instance is created, I can browse to the mounted file system at mnt/efs/fs1, but I cannot write files or create directories there.

I went into EFS in the console and edited the file system policy to this, but it still not working:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "efs-policy-wizard-a7bc160b-7c4a-43b6-abae-0905f552bf44",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "efs-statement-ca213fe8-5701-48fe-85dd-8f243a5dbce1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-east-1:198516420706:file-system/fs-02cdc4adbb7c75b71",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "elasticfilesystem:AccessedViaMountTarget": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? My goal is to create an autoscaling group, where if an instance is terminated a new one will be created and use this existing EFS file system.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Secondly, are you sure that you mounted EFS properly to your EC2 instance inside Linux (be vary, that folder you're mounting to must be empty)